# A unique solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Find the sum of all values of k so that the system
$$y=|x+23|+|x−5|+|x−48|$$$$y=2x+k$$
has exactly one solution in real numbers. If the system has one solution, then one of the three $x's$, should be 0. Then, there are 3 solutions, when each of the modulus becomes 0. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "one of the three $x$ ′ s , should be $0$": you probably mean one of the three moduli. Only one value among the three corresponds to a single solution in $x$.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps it would help to write the first equation as
$$
y=
\begin{cases}
-3x+30&\text{ for }x\leq-23\\
-x+76&\text{ for }x\in[-23,5]\\
x+66&\text{ for }x\in[5,48]\\
3x-30&\text{ for }x\geq48\\
\end{cases}
$$
Then find $x$-values of intersections with each of those four lines:
$$
\begin{align}
2x+k&=-3x+30&&\iff x=\frac{30-k}5\\
2x+k&=-x+76&&\iff x=\frac{76-k}{3}\\
2x+k&=x+66&&\iff x=66-k\\
2x+k&=3x-30&&\iff x=30+k
\end{align}
$$
and then write $k$-ranges for the valid intersections:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{30-k}{5}&\leq-23&&\iff k\geq 30+5\cdot 23 =145\\
\frac{76-k}{3}&\in[-23,5]&&\iff k\in[76-3\cdot 5,76+3\cdot 23]=[61,145]\\
66-k&\in[5,48]&&\iff k\in[18,61]\\
30+k&\geq 48&&\iff k\geq 18
\end{align}
$$
So whenever $k$ is in one of the following four intervals, $y=2x+k$ has a legal intersection with the corresponding segment of $y=|x+23|+|x-5|+|x-48|$:
$$
\begin{align}
-3x+30:&k\in[145,\infty)\\
-x+76:&k\in[61,145]\\
x+66:&k\in[18,61]\\
3x-30:&k\in[18,\infty)
\end{align}
$$
and we see that only for $k=18$ we have $y=2x+k$ intersecting $y=x+66$ and $y=3x-30$ at the same point, $x=66-18=30+18=48$.

---

Here is a diagram of the situtation:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Working with String's initial boundaries, we have
$$
0=
\begin{cases}
-5x+30-k&\text{ for }x\leq-23\\
-3x+76-k&\text{ for }x\in[-23,5]\\
-x+66-k&\text{ for }x\in[5,48]\\
x-30-k&\text{ for }x\geq48\\
\end{cases}
$$
Now notice that the function is decreasing for $x<48$ and increasing for $x>48$. This means that the function $f(x)=y-2x-k$ has a global minimum at $x=48$. Since the function is continuous (it is a sum of absolute value functions and a linear function which are each continuous), when $k=18$, $x=48$ is the unique solution of $f(x)=0$; when $k>18$, the function has two roots; when $k<18$, the function has none. Hence the only time when there is a unique solution is when $k=18$. To picture why this is, think of the curve $y=x^2-k$ and its roots.

Comment: A sum of continuous functions need not be continuous. I think you mean the sum of continuous functions is piecewise continuous and in this case since the end points "match" then we have a continuous function

Comment: @HBeel: I could believe the claim that an infinite sum of continuous functions does not have to be continuous, but the sum of finitely many continuous functions is surely continuous? Or do I forget something?

Comment: @Pakk I guess it's how you define summing two continuous functions. If two continuous functions on the same domain I believe their would be continuous. But it seems here you're "glueing" functions and if we have a function that is 0 for $x<0$ and a function that is 1 for $x \geq 0$, then there is a discontinuity at 0 when combined  yet both functions are continuous on their respective domains. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your solution but it seems like you're adding functions on disjoint domains

Comment: @HBeel: It is not my solution, I am only commenting. I think that a (finite) sum of continuous functions is always continuous, but you are right that Pauly B's solution is not a sum of continuous functions, so this argument is not valid. It is easily seen from the definition that it is piecewise continuous, and it is straightforward to check that the endpoints match, to the function is continuous. Sorry, just nitpicking. ;)

Comment: Yes you're correct. I am using "sum" incorrectly, I was trying to mimick Pauly's usage of the term. No worries, I am nitpicking too!

Comment: @Pakk: Why do you not think that $x\mapsto |x|$ is continuous? It is, and therefore $$f(x)=|x+23|+|x-5|+|x-48|-2x+k$$ is simply compositions and sums of continuous functions and thus continuous. I upvoted this anwer BTW :)

Comment: Ah I see you guys  assumed I was talking about the piecewise definition of the function, when I was thinking of the function String described above in his comment. In that case it is a sum of continuous functions. I guess I should have been a little more explicit :P

Comment: I editted it, I hope my argument is more obvious now

Comment: @String and Pauly B: put in that way, it is obvious f(x) is continuous! :)

Answer (score 0):

$$y-2x$$ is a piecewise linear function and is convex. The slope is nowhere zero (slope values are $-5,-3,-1,1$) so that it achieves an isolated minimum, which is the requested value of $k$, at the lowest vertex.

$$\begin{align}-23&\to145\\5&\to61\\48&\to\color{green}{18}\end{align}$$